# Video Not playing error(The Player might not support the file type or might not support the codec that was used to compress the file.)

Tags: java

Error in video player::-(The Player might not support the file type or might not support the codec that was used to compress the file.).When i played splitted video it show above error

```js
int splitSize = inputStream.available() / totalPartsToSplit;
            int streamSize = 0;
            int read = 0;
            System.err.println("<<<<  <<<<"+splitSize);
            while ((read = inputStream.read()) != -1) { 
             System.err.println("<<"+streamSize);
                if (splitSize == streamSize) {
                 System.err.println("<<<<<while<<"+splitSize+"steamsize--"+streamSize);
                    if (i != totalPartsToSplit) {
                        i++;
                        String fileCount = String.format("%02d", i); // output will be 1 is 01, 2 is 02
                        videoFile = splitFile.getAbsolutePath() +"/"+ fileCount +"_"+ file.getName();
                        outputStream = new FileOutputStream(videoFile);
                        System.out.println("File Created Location: "+ videoFile);
                        streamSize = 0;
                    }
                }
                outputStream.write(read);
                streamSize++;
            }
```